Log out from Intuit programmatically, Java, Sping, Thymeleaf
I created a Java application to consume Intuit API, I followed the steps:
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/sdks-and-samples-collections/java
This works for me. The problem is when I want to get the user logged out. According to the documentation, the most apparent feature is the "disconnection" Step 16 on the next page:
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0
I invalidate the session and "delete" the cookies from my backend. I don't use other cookies except JSESSIONID (all the authorization information is managed using Redis).
public void disconnectFromQuickbooks(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                String clientId = factory.getOAuth2Config().getClientId();
                String clientSecret = factory.getOAuth2Config().getClientSecret();
                OAuth2Config oauth2Config = new OAuth2Config.OAuth2ConfigBuilder(clientId, clientSecret)
                        .callDiscoveryAPI(getEnvironment(environment)).buildConfig();
                OAuth2PlatformClient client = new OAuth2PlatformClient(oauth2Config);

                revokeToken(client, getSessionAttribute(session, "refresh_token"));
                revokeToken(client, getSessionAttribute(session, "access_token"));

                invalidateSessionAndClearCookie(request, response);
            }
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

the first part disconnect my application from Intuit, the invalidateSessionAndClearCookie(request, response) is how y try to log out the user
public void invalidateSessionAndClearCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            String sessionId = session.getId();
            session.invalidate();

            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
            if (cookies != null) {
                for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                    if ("JSESSIONID".equals(cookie.getName()) && sessionId.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                        cookie.setValue(null);
                        cookie.setDomain(request.getServerName());
                        cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
                        cookie.setSecure(request.isSecure());
                        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

When the entire flow is executed, the JSESSIONID remains in the browser (A different one, but still valid). Spring regenerates the cookie, and the user remains logged in(the user doesn't see the login prompt).
Does anyone else have this same problem? How could this problem be handled?
